# Regx for email address which should not accept 2 consecutive hyphen and period?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a regex for email address which should not accept 2 consecutive hyphen and period

Currently I am using following expression.

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})$
```

Above expression finely working with periods but not for hyphen.
I need to use this expression in data annotation in .net MVC 4 application.

Comment: `<input type="email" />` Done.

Comment: So many things wrong with that regex.`this.valid.address+will+not+work@example.travel`

Comment: And more importantly, "two hyphens in domain part are invalid"? Welcome to the new millenium: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domains

Comment: I tried with following expression ""^[_A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})|([_A-Za-z0-9]+(\-[_A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}))$". It work finely but not with consecutive one hyphen and one period.

Answer (score 0):

How about this . .

```
^(?=.*[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(?!.*(\.\.|--)).*
```